# view the two buttons side by side

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

I have two buttons Login and Scan. I want these buttons to be in a horizontal way just like in a single row. I tied making the layout horizontal. However it does not work. They should appear side by side. My code is as follows.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/imagesand"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/imagesand"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="207dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/loginbg"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="User Name"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/emailid"
            android:layout_width="156dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:hint="User Name"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="Password"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="156dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/login"
            android:layout_width="71dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/login"

            android:text="Login"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:typeface="serif" />

        <Button android:id="@+id/scan"
            and 
            android:layout_width="71dp" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
              android:layout_marginTop="15dp" 
              android:layout_weight="1" 
              android:background="@drawable/login"
               android:text="scan"/>
    </LinearLayout>

   </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Surely one of these answers helped you, why havn't you accepted or commented on any?

Answer (score 2):

Just put both button in `LinearLayout` whose orientation must be `horizontal`

Answer (score 2):

Simple use this..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1"
         android:text="Scan"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this code:

<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/imagesand"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="207dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/loginbg"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="User Name"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/emailid"
                android:layout_width="156dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:hint="User Name"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:text="Password"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="156dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />
      <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/login"
                android:layout_width="71dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/login"

                android:text="Login"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:typeface="serif" />

            <Button android:id="@+id/scan"
                and 
                android:layout_width="71dp" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                  android:layout_marginTop="15dp" 
                  android:layout_weight="1" 
                  android:background="@drawable/login"
                   android:text="scan"/>
    </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

       </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either wrap the buttons within a horizontal LinearLayout like this:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="71dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/login"

        android:text="Login"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/scan"
        android:layout_width="71dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" 
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:background="@drawable/login"
        android:text="scan"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

or use a `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

RealtiveLayout is the best choice:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<Button
android:id="@+id/button01"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_below="@id/entry" 
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/space"
/>
<TextView
android:id="@id/space"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
<Button
android:id="@+id/button02"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@id/entry" 
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
/>  
</RelativeLayout>
```

Seems like you want two equal buttons, not wrapped content. I created a centered spacer using TextView, and relatively aligned to that. Left button to parent left and spacer, Right button to Left Button and parent right.

Answer (score 0):

This should works:

Change these,

```
   <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="71dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/login"

        android:text="Login"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/scan"
        and 
        android:layout_width="71dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="15dp" 
          android:layout_weight="1" 
          android:background="@drawable/login"
           android:text="scan"/>
```

with this,

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/login"
            android:layout_width="71dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/login"
            android:text="Login"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:typeface="serif" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/scan"
            android:layout_width="71dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/login"
            android:text="scan" />
    </LinearLayout>
```